# How do I test the localization of a website by changing local settings?

Tags: windows-7, website, localization

I published an application in the Google play store and the description should be supporting localization.

How can I change my local localization?
Is it the Windows 7 settings? The browser settings? Both?

I'm not sure how it works or what affects the site localization.

Comment: Contact Google with regards to this question.

Comment: @Ramhound, why would Google be able to help change the language settings on your desktop computer?

Comment: @heavyd - Because the regional settings of Google Play isn't dependent on the operating system's language?  I am not even sure how this is connected to Windows 7 in any capacity.

Comment: Pretty sure he's talking about accessing http://play.google.com, from a browser on a Windows desktop, in which case the browser would use the OS language settings to request a localized version of the website.

Comment: If it's play.google.com then it is using IP location (?) not OS language settings (I'm getting a dutch language page in NL while using a UK language configured OS)

Comment: @DavidPostill - is there a way to change my IP to other country ? use proxy or something ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the old one, but answering for the sake of other users:

The simplest way for you to display Google Play in any language you want is to add `&hl=xx` where `xx` represents locale code(i.e. `&hl=pl` for Polish, or `&hl=de` for German). Make sure you add it to the URL of your application, like `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.ma2.f2p.google&hl=pl`

Google(and all it's services that I know of), use geoLocation by IP address, so changing your OS or browser settings won't affect the website language that their website will be shown to you in.

Now, there is another way for you to, let's say *fake* your IP address by connecting to a website using proxy. You need to find one(search the internet for websites providing free proxy lists), find a one that will make your packets go over country you want to test your localization for, and then add it to your browser settings. This one goes for any website you're visiting.